# AndroidthingsでMG811（二酸化炭素センサー）は使うことができるのか

Tags: android, android-studio, raspberry-pi, センサー

ラズパイとセンサーで二酸化炭素を測り、高すぎたら警報を鳴らすというアプリを作りたいのですが、以下の組み合わせで二酸化炭素の値を取得することは可能なのかをお聞きしたいです。一番懸念しているのはAndroid Thingsのデータ呼び出し速度です。
端末：Raspberry Pi 3 Model B
OS：Androidthings
センサー名：二酸化炭素センサモジュール　MG811/MG-811 CO2　0-2V　 0-10000ppm
購入先：www.amazon.co.jp/dp/B01HCQQGM0
センサーのスペック：
http://sandboxelectronics.com/files/SEN-000007/MG811.pdf
http://sandboxelectronics.com/?p=147

Android Thingsのデータの呼び出し速度は遅いため正確な値を取得できるかを懸念しています。Android Thingsでは、GPIOから一つのデータを呼び出すのに230usかかります。もし、MG811に必要な呼び出し速度をご存知のかたがいれば、教えていただけたら幸いです。
https://qiita.com/soundTricker/items/661a1034f50da773c799
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37135689

Comment: 呼び出し速度が遅いことでどういうことが起きることを懸念されていますか？

Comment: DHT11というセンサーでは、GPIOからtrue、falseのデータを20us毎に読み取り、読み取った大量true,falseを数値に変換するコードが必要らしいです。この読み取り速度がAndroid Thingsでは230usなので、20usに追いつきません。かなりの取りこぼしが発生してしまい正確な値が取得できないかもしれないと懸念しておりました。参考記事：https://qiita.com/soundTricker/items/661a1034f50da773c799

Answer (score 1):

> Android Thingsでは、GPIOから一つのデータを呼び出すのに230us

230us は　0.23msで気温、室温などの計測用途では、全然早いのですが、リンク先の
二酸化炭素センサモジュールのデータシート見ました、`Response and Resume Characteristic　（Figure 3）`の項目にセンサーの応答速度の表が有り、時間軸の単位は「時間（ｓ）」と親切に書き込んであるので、Figure 3グラフから　センサーがガスに反応して１〜４秒ぐらいのゆっくりした電圧変化が読み取れます。(MG811はアナログ出力のセンサーですね)

普通にプログラムすれば、読み取れると思います。

最後に、デバッグ時　酸欠に注意です。！

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございました！挑戦してみます。